# How to find duplicate element dict of list in python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How to find max duplicate values in the list of dict in python?

for example

```
 smp_dict =
 { 0: [18, 2, 17, 12, 15, 0, 3],
   1: [13, 0, 3, 11, 4],
   2: [18, 2, 17, 12, 15, 8],
   3: [17, 12, 15, 5, 0, 3, 11],
   4: [9, 13]}
```

Output I expect

```
 result = [17,12,15,0,3,13,11]
```

result[0] = most common value  and result[-1] = least common value

please help me

Comment: Do the keys have any meaning? Or is this just another representation of a single list?

Comment: Where are the other values ? like 9, 5, 8 ? not all values are used ?

Answer (score 4):

You may use a `collections.Counter` in which you put all values of all values from dict, then keep the keys (the item) ordered by occurence

```
from collections import Counter

smp_dict = {
    0: [18, 2, 17, 12, 15, 0, 3],
    1: [13, 0, 3, 11, 4],
    2: [18, 2, 17, 12, 15, 8],
    3: [17, 12, 15, 5, 0, 3, 11],
    4: [9, 13]
}

c = Counter(x for sublist in smp_dict.values() for x in sublist)
# {17: 3, 12: 3, 15: 3, 0: 3, 3: 3, 18: 2, 2: 2, 13: 2, 11: 2, 4: 1, 8: 1, 5: 1, 9: 1}

result = [x[0] for x in c.most_common()]
print(result)  # [17, 12, 15, 0, 3, 18, 2, 13, 11, 4, 8, 5, 9]
```